# What happens to the debris of a rocket that exploded or crashed? Is there a dedicated effort to cleaning the debris?

Tags: rockets, debris

Assuming that everything is not vaporized, one would think that all waste is collected and incinerated. Does SpaceX, NASA, etc have a dedicated team/effort to cleaning up this debris?

Comment: I have edited the question, and hopefully it is now more clear.

Comment: In the case of challenger it was collected, investigated and then buried: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Challenger_disaster#Recovery_of_debris_and_crew

For Columbia it was collected, investigated and then stored in the VAB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Columbia_disaster#Recovery_of_debris

Comment: However the primary motivation generally seems to be finding clues as to why the rocket exploded, not cleanup.

Comment: Wayne Hayles Blog (especially the [parts about Columbia](https://waynehale.wordpress.com/tag/columbia-accident/)) is an excellent source of anectodal evidence for this kind of thing.

Comment: The original question was specifically about SpaceX. I wonder if the edits have changed the intent.

Comment: If the debris falls into a deep sea are, cleaning the debris would need a lot of time, equipment and money. Collecting the Soyuz debris in the Baikonur area is done to earn money. No explosion or crash, just used booster stages.

Comment: Rocket debris recovery is more aimed at: public safety(volatiles, etc), then absconding with any SuperSecret stuff, then investigating mishaps(if any), then ordinary don't-litter cleanup.  Not everything, not even **nearly** everything gets cleaned up. Especially from oceans. They were still dredging up F1 rocket motors from Apolo11 out of the Atlantic, as recently as 2013, 44 years later! https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2013/03/20/174834978/we-have-liftoff-apollo-rocket-engines-reportedly-pulled-from-ocean-floor   Also note the funny debris each chinese launch drops on villages, etc.

Comment: Appreciate all the responses. @StarMan - although I was specifically referring to the SpaceX crashes, the protocol appears to be similar with all agencies so this was helpful.